# Can't select these areas no matter what so as result it appears white in renders

Tags: texturing, vertex-groups

Here is non rendered image of my project.[image]

Comment: Switching to wireframe mode might selecting the areas in between. Looks like you've got modifiers applied (perhaps solidify?) which hinders the selection.

Comment: Thanks for the response bro. Actually i have applied array modifier and solidify too.Can't able to select in wireframe .

Comment: Are you certain that these faces are in the same object? Could it be that you separated them into another object by accident?

Comment: Yes bro its on same object and if i select all by ' A' then too these faces are not selected.

Comment: There are only two options, either you just can't see that it's selected because of the modifier or the faces aren't part of the mesh. Try to do the following, go to the modifier tab and for all modifier disable *Display modifier in edit mode* (the icon of the box with vertices, right next to the icon with the eye). If you can now see the faces it was the modifier blocking the view (likely solidify). By the looks of it you might also want to check that you don't have inverted normals on these faces.

Comment: Bro by disabling solidy modifier i can select those faces but that deform my mesh .Is there any chance i can solidify it again after adding textures.

Comment: It's not actually changing the mesh, just hiding the modifier in edit mode. When you switch back to object mode or render you'll see that the modifier is still active.

Comment: Thanks dude you are a saviour!